# when i am using react-responsive-carousel in react it's showing nothing in my browser even not showing any error in my code also

Tags: reactjs, react-responsive-carousel, react-responsive

my question is about react-responsive carousel ?
when I am using react-responsive-carousel in react it's showing nothing in my browser even not showing any error in my code also

i checked my code many times but i unable to find any error or correction in it.

Comment: Please add code snippet you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please send the code that you are trying to implement?
I have added an example for you here, which you can [check](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/misty-cdn-qn42jf?file=%2Fsrc%2FCarousel.js%3A12%2C11&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gcea0006356nkqvxblv2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90002356np5zo7g59%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90003356nysxoibpk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90005356ntjx7vryg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls49gce90002356np5zo7g59%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90002356np5zo7g59%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls4ao5i90002356nopx1ubbj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A11%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A11%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FCarousel.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls4ao5i90002356nopx1ubbj%2522%257D%252C%2522cls49gce90005356ntjx7vryg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90004356nitlwybdm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90005356ntjx7vryg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90004356nitlwybdm%2522%257D%252C%2522cls49gce90003356nysxoibpk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls49gce90003356nysxoibpk%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).